# Doesn't compare time before 10 am

Tags: java, date, parsing, time, localtime

I'm making a time comparison in a loop. So it checks me all the times saved in `HH:mm` format, and then it does other instructions.
If i try to compare a time that's between `00:00` and `09:59`, it gives me error.
What can i do?

```
for(int contatore = 0; lista_allarmi.moveToNext() ; contatore++) {
    Date ORANOTIFICA;
    ID_M = lista_allarmi.getInt(0);
    NOME_M = lista_allarmi.getString(1);
    TIPO_M = lista_allarmi.getString(2);
    String ora_notifica = lista_allarmi.getString(3);
    parts = ora_notifica.split(":");
    hrs = Integer.parseInt(parts[0]); // ore
    min = Integer.parseInt(parts[1]); // minuti
    ora_allm.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,hrs);
    ora_allm.set(Calendar.MINUTE, min);
    ora_allm.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    ora_allm_piut = ora_allm;
    ora_allm_piut.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 5);
    hrs = ora_allm_piut.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    min = ora_allm_piut.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    HPT = String.valueOf(hrs);
    MPT = String.valueOf(min);
    ORARNPT = HPT + ":" + MPT; ORANOTIFICAPIUTIMER;
    Date ora_attuale = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
    Date ORARIOATT;

    i = new Intent(getContext(), AlarmReceiver.class);
    i.putExtra("id", ID_M);
    i.putExtra("NMM", NOME_M);
    i.putExtra("TPM", TIPO_M);
    pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getContext(), contatore, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    if(LocalTime.now().isAfter(parse(ora_notifica)) && LocalTime.now().isBefore(parse(ORARNPT))) {
         //A
    } else {
         //B
    }
}
```

Comment: could you show what `parse(ora_notifica)` does?

Comment: Thank you for posting _some_ code, but this isn't enough for people to quickly spot an error, and neither did you include the error which you get. If it is an exception, include the full stacktrace. For the code, create a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and post it here.

Comment: Have you tried to debug your code?

Comment: `lista_allarmi.moveToNext()` looks like a really strange limit in a `for` loop.

Comment: Debugger: `java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '9:25' could not be parsed at index 0` but i've saved the time as 09:25

Comment: @FedericoChiaradia Post further details as edits to the Question rather than as a Comment.

Comment: In your last comment, you quote an error from parsing in *java.time* classes, but I see no *java.time* parsing in your source code above. Please take more care to be thorough and well-written before posting on Stack Overflow. And take the time to write short contrived example code rather than cut-and-paste your live code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to add a "0" when the hour taken with Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY  was <=9 :

```
hrs=ora_allm_piut.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
min=ora_allm_piut.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
if(hrs<=9){HPT=String.valueOf("0"+hrs);
```

Now the time respect the time format, and i can make the comparison.

Answer (score 2):

## tl;dr

```
LocalTime.parse(
    "9:25" ,
    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "H:m" )
)
.isBefore(
    LocalTime.of( 10 , 0 ) 
)
```

## You are using the wrong classes

Never use the terribly troublesome old date-time classes bundled with the earliest versions of Java. These are now legacy, supplanted entirely by the *java.time* classes built into Java 8 and later. Avoid `Date`, `Calendar`, and `SimpleDateFormat` altogether.

## Format must match input

> HH:mm format

…

> java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '9:25' could not be parsed at index 0

Your formatting pattern says `HH` which means two digit value. For hours 1-9, a leading padding zero is expected. Your input of `9:25` is missing its padding zero.

For such input, use a single `H`. And likely the minutes lack a padding zero, so use a single `m` there too.

> DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "H:m" )

## Do not work so hard

The *java.time* classes will parse your string inputs for you. No need to analyze the text yourself.

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "H:m" ) ;
LocalTime lt = LocalTime.parse( "9:25" , f ) ;
```

## Half-Open

> compare a time that's between 00:00 and 09:59,

When defining a span of time, the Half-Open approach is generally the best. In this approach, the beginning is considered *inclusive* while the ending is *exclusive*. This means the hour of 9 AM starts at 09:00 and runs up to, but does not include, the first moment of the following hour, 10:00.

One benefit of Half-Open is that you avoid trying to nail down the ever-divisible last moment of the hour. Is the last moment 09:59? 09:59.9? 09:59.999999999? Avoid the entire debacle by instead asking “Is the moment *before* 10 AM?“.

For time-of-day only, without the context of a date, the clock stops at midnight. So if you want ask if a certain time of day is between midnight and 10 AM, you need only ask if it is before 10 AM.

```
LocalTime stop = LocalTime.of( 10 , 0 );
LocalTime x = LocalTime.parse( "09:25" ) ;
Boolean isEarlyEnough = x.isBefore( stop ) ;
```

Perhaps you want to use a starting time other than first moment of the day. In that case, specify a start as well as a stop.

```
LocalTime start = LocalTime.MIN ;  // Constant for 00:00:00.000000000.
LocalTime stop = LocalTime.of( 10 , 0 );
LocalTime x = LocalTime.parse( "09:25" ) ;
Boolean isEarlyEnoughButNotTooEarly = ( ! x.isBefore( start ) ) &&  x.isBefore( stop ) ;  // "Not before" is a briefer way of saying "Is equal to or later than".
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).